# HTML Canvas height defaults to 1 after slideToggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I have the following code to define a chart inside of a js file.

```
"<div class='col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3' id='" + firstName + lastName + 
       primaryCompensationCode + "COLME' style='position: relative;'>",
"<canvas id="firstName + lastName + primaryCompensationCode + "ME",
" height='260' width='260' responsive></canvas>",
"</div>",
```

The code is in the form of a string, because I build the layout of the chart within a card and append that to the document. I also have a function that will expand and collapse the card, including the charts, but this is where the issue lies. After expanding the chart after collapsing it, or adding more cards, the chart height defaults to 1 while the width auto-adjusts to fill the space. I cant see any reason why the height wouldn't auto adjust as well and at no point am I defining a height and width besides when the chart is constructed. Any thoughts?

Here's what it looks like when you first open the card:
[image: Open]

and here's what it looks like when you close and re-open the card:
[image: Open2]

and here's where the height is defaulting to 1:

[image: Open3]

There are three charts and an image all contained in the body of a card. When the header of the card is clicked, the following function is called which collapses the card into the card header.

```
expandCard: function(clicked_id) {
    var advisorCard = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    $(advisorCard).nextUntil('div.card-header').slideToggle(1);
}
```

When the elements load into the page, the cards are collapsed by default. So here's where the issue is: If you add a card (card1) and don't expand it, then add another card (card2). Then card2 expands and shows the charts just fine, whereas card1's charts have a height of 1. The div that contains each chart (the bootstrap column) also has a height of 1 in this scenario.

Comment: Try get height of parrent container and set her for canvas height.

Comment: parent of the chart is a div, and the parent of that is another div. When the card is closed, both divs and charts have heights of 0 X 0 since they're not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note, looks like for the `responsive` attribute to work correctly, the parent element needs to be sized using relative units. Their code example is:

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: So even with that change, Height is still defaulting to 0px.

Comment: Can you add more supporting code to show what's actually happening when you "close and re-open the card"?

Comment: I think the issue is that for the responsive nature to work, the resizing of the chart needs to be/should be done through the `chart` object. In that same link, they show resizing as `chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '128px';`. Maybe wrap the `canvas` in its own parent element inside of the bootstrap column, then give the column element `overflow: hidden`, so that you're never directly manipulating the chart parent's size.

Comment: Okay so that didn't work, however I did find a workaround. Each time the card is expanded, I'm now re-drawing the graphs.